# Session variables set - Page_Load method C#

Tags: c#, session

I tried to link default1.aspx and default 2.aspx.

What I'm trying to do is to display calculated results in default1.aspx when clicking confirm button in default2.aspx.

I run the codes but it doesn't work really.
How can I fix this?

I wrote the codes in default1.aspx below:

```
protected void confirmBookingButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("RoomBookingMain.aspx");
    Session["confirmBooking"] = "confirm";
    Session["totalBooking"] = calculateTextBox.Text;
}
```

and then I wrote other codes in default2.aspx like:

```
public partial class RoomBookingMain : System.Web.UI.Page
{
static int nbBookingInt = 0;
static int totalRevenueInt = 0;
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bookingNbLabel.Text = nbBookingInt.ToString();
    totRevenueLabel.Text = totalRevenueInt.ToString();
    string confirmBooking = (string)(Session["confirmBooking"]);
    if ((string)(Session["confirmBooking"]) == "confirm")
    {
        nbBookingInt += 1;
        totalRevenueInt += int.Parse(Session["totalBooking"].ToString());
        Session["confirmBooking"] = "no current booking";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Session["confirmBooking"] = "confirm";
Session["totalBooking"] = calculateTextBox.Text;
Response.Redirect("RoomBookingMain.aspx");
```

Assign Session before Response.Redirect(). Redirect method will stop the execution at that point.

If you need to pass the data only to next page and if no secure data is involved you can use [QueryStrings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString).

Comment: "When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to false and then call the CompleteRequest method. If you specify true for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the End method for the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web application performance, which is why passing false for the endResponse parameter is recommended." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx